# Faddeev - Kulish paper questions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, research-level, infrared-radiation

I have several questions regarding the paper [Asymptotic conditions and infrared divergences in QED](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01066485), written by Faddeev and Kulish in 1970. This is not a post about one question, but since all the following questions are related, I hope that the admins will allow it.

1. In order to derive the expression that describes the asymptotic behavior of the potential term in the QED Hamiltonian, the authors use the mode expansions of both the spinor and the guage fields. On top of that, they identify the energies carried by the spinor fields and the guage fields to be on shell. Doesn't that contradict the fact that the field configurations are not anymore time-evovled by the free Hamiltonian anymore at the asymptotic regions of space (you know, becuase being time-evovled by the free Hamiltonian means they obey the free EoMs)?
2. At some point, the authors derive a Schroedinger-like equation, obeyed by the asymptotic time-evolution operator. The authors assume a solution of the form $U_{as}(t)=e^{iH_0t}Z(t)$. For a solution such as this to exist, isn't it implied that the $Z(t)$ operator is going to be some exponential operator, whose exponent shall commute with the free Hamiltonian??
3. When trying to derive an expression for the commutator of the asymptotic potential with itself, $Q(\tau,s)=[V_{as}(\tau),V_{as}(s)]$, the authors use the fact that the charge density obeys
   $$\rho(\vec{p})\rho(\vec{q})=:\rho(\vec{p})\rho(\vec{q}):+\delta^{(3)}(\vec{p}-\vec{q})\sum_s[b_s^{\dagger}(\vec{p})b_s(\vec{p})+d_s^{\dagger}(\vec{p})d_s(\vec{p})]$$
   where $b_s(\vec{p})$ and $d_s(\vec{p})$ are annihilation operators associated to fermions and their corresponding antiparticles. They claim that the term in $Q(\tau,s)$ originating from the second term "contributes to the renormalization of the mass of charged particles". Why is that?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: May I ask what research project you are working on?

Comment: I am not working on a specific project so far. I am just trying to understand the paper written by these authors and Strominger's lecture notes.

Comment: Obviously I understand that. But you’re asking loads of questions recently based on Strominger’s lectures so I was just curious about what you’re working on.

Comment: Hi @Prahar. As I said, I haven't yet started working on a specific project yet. I think my project will involve the study of scattering processes accompanied by infrared radiation. Probably it will somehow involve the dressed state formalism, developed in the current paper, but I can not be too sure, as I haven't started it yet. For the time being, I am simply trying to understand the background. Why do you ask though, if you don't mind me asking. I hope I haven't done anything annoying. I apologise if I have overstepped my bounds in any way...

Comment: no dude. You haven’t done anything at all. It’s just that this is my field of research and you’re studying several of my papers so I got curious.

Comment: Oh okay then... If you are still interested when I know more, I can let you know :)